# knockoutjs, custom bindings and knockoutjs templates (calling knockoutjs templates from custom bindings init method)

Tags: knockout.js

I want to hook third party controls into knockoutjs and using custom bindings to join them together. So far it works fine. But there are few controls where I want to choose templates to 
render controls. But could not find any way to call knockout js templates through javascript.

Is it is possible.

---

```
<div data-bind = "knockoutjs-text : data, label : labelText"></div>

// got following template in seperate file
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>

// my custom binding handler in seperate file
ko.bindingHandlers.knockoutjs-text = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // now it want to call person-template from here and attached it to element


}
```

};

This is simple example for my case, My case to create user controls, b combining these two together. 
If you think this example is not enough please let me know.

Thanks,
Daljit Singh

Comment: Can you show us some example code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have exactly this problem now. How did you get on with this, OK it was 18 months ago, but I'm only just coming up to this issue. I've tried to do this with Handlebarjs, however either it won't work, or I'm doing something wrong.
Whist the example below looks like it could work, it doesn't feel right; working code though beats broken code.

Comment: Hi zeristor, It was for a personnel project, but i never actually tried anything and write a code, I am not sure if this help, but there is ko.rendertemplate method in knockoutjs, if not let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use dynamic templates:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="LoadingTemplate">Loading...</script>
```

Update the script tag after download of the template:

```
self.Content = ko.observable("<b>Hello World</b>");
self.TemplateID = ko.observable("LoadingTemplate");
self.UniquePageID = ko.observable(GenerateUUID());  // create a random id

ko.computed(function () {
    var html = self.Content(),
        uniqueID = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.UniquePageID),
        templateID = "template_" + uniqueID;

    // remove the current template
    $("#" + templateID).remove();

    // append the html template
    $("body").append('<script type="text/html" id="' + templateID + '">' + html + '</script>');

    // update the template ID (this will trigger the knockoutjs data-bindings)
    self.TemplateID(templateID);

}).extend({ throttle: 100 });
```

See [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/using-external-jquery-template-files.html) on knockmeout.net for more information.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will give it a go. I did not accept as answer, because I have not try it, I look it is going to work for my scenrio. Thanks again for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

It may be some time since the problem was posed. I've just had to fix this, and got Handlebarsjs to work great.

I had to write a Custom-Binding for the new Typeahead.js, then I was asked to show more data in the drop down.

I followed [Typeaheadjs's Custom Template example](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) scroll down a bit. This works fine in Knockoutjs.

This is the code in question, it isn't specifically for knockoutjs, but I used this for my templates:suggestion entry successfully.

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'twitter-oss',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: repos.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
      '<p class="repo-language">{{language}}</p>',
      '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
      '<p class="repo-description">{{description}}</p>'
    ].join(''))
  }
});
```

*Be aware, Handlebars isn't spelt with a capital 'B', and since this uses the compile function you have to use the larger Handlebars.js library (currently "handlebars-v1.3.0.js"), not the runtime one.*

I have misgivings about requiring a 88kb library to do this, but I do like the cut of Handlebars' jib.